My rig looks fine on EEVEE but rig texture messes up on Cycles
I'm new to blender and I've been doing roblox renders. I'm making a 3D Render but the texture is messed up, it was fine on EEVEE then when I switched to cycles the texture was messed up all a sudden. Can anyone tell me the fix? Cause I dont really wanna redo this again, and how can I prevent this for next time.

Hello, it may be Z-Fighting (overlapping faces), or a transparency problem? If you can't fix it please share your file
